# Scanning USB stick with multiple Antivirus tools

Tags: antivirus

I realise that having multiple AVs is not recommended, but I have a specific question.

My boss supplied me with a laptop which has like 5 different AVs (some of them are more like portable "launch and scan" type AVs where they do not run all the time). The idea is that this laptop will only be used to scan USB sticks - with all of the AVs one at a time.

Now, I tried that - scanned a USB stick with each AV at a time, and I did not see any conflicts between different AVs (no viruses identified either). The laptop had good speed and no issues.

Given this result (no noticable conflict between AVs) - is it OK to be scanning USB like that?

Me personally, I don't understand what this solves - if I think that a USB is infected, I should just format it; but if it's not infected, there is no reason to be even scanning it...

Comment: Is it OK? I mean... it's not going to order a tactical nuke at your location, and it won't kill your cat. Is it effective? Only for low-hanging fruit and simple or old malware. You need to make sure the AV databases are up to date though, which is a common issue for "portable" scanners. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: @forest, obviously I update all AVs before scanning. But questions is essentially should I scan with 1 AV or with 5 AVs? Considering I did not see evidence of these AVs conflicting, I am not sure 1 would be better than all 5.

Comment: _Should_ you? Well, I think it's a waste of time, but it's not going to break anything.

Comment: @forest, Since you say it's a "waste of time" my assumption is that there is like 100% chance that other AVs will not find anything if the first one did not find any malware, am I correct? As far as I can see, even if I increase my chances just slightly in finding malware by scanning with multple AVs, then it's time well spent (considering I don't mind spending those extra 15 mins). Am I wrong?

Comment: An AV might be able to find 5% of sophisticated malware. Five AVs might be able to find 5.1%. One AV might be able to find 80% of old or common malware. Five AVs might be able to find 82%. This is a small benefit for so much extra work (in licenses, CPU time, storage, maintenance, etc.).

Comment: If I know/think/believe/wake up sweating that a USB is infected, I wipe it according to some DoD standard.

Comment: @Patriot "DoD standards" are actually utterly useless for flash devices like USB sticks.

Comment: @forest Right. A small red light flickered in the back of my mind when I said that, you caught me. If I suspect a USB is bad I destroy it. That means: use a hammer. That is straight-up DoD.  Etc.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, many anti-malware tools *do* conflict with each-other, so there's a reason that's not recommended. Any one modern and up-to-date antimalware software will do just fine.

Secondly, when you say this:

> I don't understand what does this solve - if I think that USB is infected I should just format it, and if it's not infected there is no reason to be even scanning it...

It doesn't matter what you *think*. The drive is either infected or it isn't. And it's always better to be safe rather than sorry.

Also, if there's a lot of important data on a drive, you can't just reformat it without making a backup of said data. This may take a lot of time depending on how much data you're handling. And in doing so, you will probably also end up making a copy of the malware, which is definitely a Bad Thing.

Scanning USB drives is *always* a good idea, even when they're coming from someone you trust.

Comment: _Always_? Even if the person giving it to you has a privesc for your AV software? :P

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So you would still recommend periodically scanning the USB drives, however only using a single AV tool? Does that mean that even though I did not notice any evidence of conflict, me scanning USB with 5 different AVs likely yield worse results than scanning with a single AV?

Comment: @user1880405 Yes, I recommend scanning all USB drives when they're plugged in. Lots of anti-malware will do this automatically. No, scanning with multiple AVs won't yield worse results - it's just pretty pointless and a waste of time.

Comment: @forest I realize you're joking, but seriously, considering how improbable it is that an attacker has an unpatched privesc for your AV, yes, I stand by what I said. You should always scan USB drives that have been used in computers other than your own, and by persons other than yourself.

Comment: @rahuldottech The problem with _always_ is that it's universal, so it applies not only to the average Joe (where the advice makes sense and their biggest threat is some crappy ransomware), but also to the person with TS/SCI clearance, or a huge amount of corporate secrets on his laptop as he travels to a foreign country.

Comment: @rahuldottech, but why is it a waste of time? Different AVs still use different signatures and work slightly differently. Even if I increase my chances of finding malware by 5% when scanning with all 5 AVs compared to scanning with 1, then I don't see it a waste of time (if i can spent additional 15 minutes), or you disagree?

Comment: @forest Anyone other than an average Joe shouldn't be getting advice from a stranger on a random website on the internet.

Comment: @rahuldottech You'd be surprised how often high-profile targets with millions of dollars worth of corporate assets on their laptops are no more knowledgeable than the average Joe that searches Google, stumbles upon this site, and proceeds to implement any advice given here, complete with qualifiers like "always".

Comment: @user1880405 I don't disagree, per se. But I still believe that any one AV is enough for >99% of consumers. Go ahead and scan with multiple AVs if you have the time and resources. But if you believe that you're a high-value target, then you need to have more security measures than just "multiple AVs" in place (such a sandboxed, disposable testing machine for external drives, a proper security policy, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Multiple AV scanners on a dedicated scanning machine is standard practice at many (*perhaps all*) high security locations and required use for bringing in all outside software.

**Yes it's OK to be scanning a USB like that.**

One can argue the value in selected circumstances but it's not harmful technically.

Bureaucratically it can lead to having to explain malware alerts that are not malware but may be declared "***Bad***". Many forensic or technical tools such as hex editors occasionally fall in this category. Offline virus signature update files will send scanners into fits because they are full of virus signatures, which in turn leads to having to explain that to non-technical people.

Not all scanners detect the same things so running many of them, sequentially to prevent interference, is useful although it can be time consuming.

Being required to run multiple Windows AV scanners against terrabyte Linux images can make you crazy, but it takes longer to fight than to just do it.

Comment: I agree with this answer because I have ignored the usual advice and used two, three, four, five AVs at a time. Once you see that some AVs miss stuff, you will not go back to using just one.

Answer (score 0):

Antivirus normally installs himself in the computer as a rootkit. 
As any good rootkit they do not like competition. (unless they are portable av)

For the scanning I would suggest you to disable auto play on the device, then use the following command "dir/w/o/a/p" (no quotes) to see what is inside.

If you do not see any malicious file that can be used in the autoplay or any file that seems suspicious executable, it is good...

now you just need to worry with the files...

To check the files with the all possible antivirus just grab the files and use virus total page he will provide you feedback from lots of AV immediately.

Comment: Uploading your sensitive work files to VirusTotal is a good way to get fired.

Comment: you know the AV are doing the same in your computer and upload files that they do not recognize or find them suspicious to their hub for latter analysis...  Did you read how the Karspersky got the NSA files?

Comment: Depends on the AV. Also, if you have a 16 GiB flash drive and it's full, good luck uploading that all to VirusTotal without getting your IP severely ratelimited.

Comment: You just need to upload all the suspicious files with some logic, the dir was to search for the suspicious.  In reallity it really does not matter if you have an AV or not windows tends to do it with the Microsoft Defender Advanced Threat Protection and it is in their license agreement. They do not get all files but if their tool notices a suspicious execution path from a file it will get delivered to the Microsoft for analysis. If you have big $$ you can access their portal and see, it is really cool for forensics and to understand what might have happened.

Comment: @Hugo it seems you are speculating all AV company want your file.  If what you claim is true, Malware writer may have already uploaded terabytes of junk files and bankrupt AV company on storage cost.

Comment: No I did not claim they want our files I claim that there is no difference from Virus Total check of unknown suspicious files and a local AV check. The information that is gathered and sent to the company is the same.

Comment: If you ask me about my opinion on the AV, is that from a security point of view in some conflict they are the biggest botnet that is build in legal way. Even if they are not malicious now because they can update at anytime their functions and it is in their LA that makes them weaponizable, thus a interesting risk if you have the wrong AV installed in a conflict situation.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cheap but not efficient solution, i.e. if the USB number increase, imagine the load to trigger run of each AV.

Most AV company actually has a dedicated file scanner for business for such needs. You should look into such option.

However, the business product is usually licensed differently.